# Sliding Puzzle in Java, need help understanding this method

Tags: java, android

I am following an online tutorial for building a Sliding Puzzle in Java on Android Studios and I need help understanding this method.

Here it is, I've never seen something like the return before. I know it is bit shifting but I have no clue how that works. Also, left is 0, right is 1, up is 2, down is 3. Thanks

```
public int getPossibleMoves() {
    int x = getColumnAt(handleLocation);
    int y = getRowAt(handleLocation);

    boolean left = x > 0;
    boolean right = x < width - 1;
    boolean up = y > 0;
    boolean down = y < height - 1;

    return(left ? 1 << DIRECTION_LEFT : 0) |
            (right ? 1 << DIRECTION_RIGHT : 0) |
            (up ? 1 << DIRECTION_UP : 0) |
            (down ? 1 << DIRECTION_DOWN : 0);
}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

The statement in the return is called **Conditional expressions**.

**Conditional expressions** are in a completely different style, with no explicit if in the statement. The syntax is:

```
boolean-expression ? expression1 : expression2;
```

The result of this **conditional expression** is expression1 if boolean-expression is true; otherwise the result is expression2 .